# smartgit Push: Not all refs have been pushed

Tags: git, github, smartgit

I have started to learn Git for a week,and I'm facing with a problem at work. The thing is I have made some changes while I was in `develop` branch and after I finish my work I tried to commit and push,however, I could not get rid of last error. Here you can see s screenshot of the smartgit and logs.

[image]

also you can see the log file here;

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just make

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git push
```

you have this error because there are some new commits in the remote develop branch which you do not have in your local develop branch , this changes has to be fetch first

Comment: hey Vlad. I did what you say and I guess it work but after push command. It gives the same error. This is my log for commands.
after `git checkout develope`;
`Already on 'develop'
Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
and have 2 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)`. after `git pull` --> `Already up-to-date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.` and finally after push -->! [rejected]        feature/HS-41 -> feature/HS-41 (non-fast-forward)

Comment: and what happened after you made `git pull` ?

Comment: here you can see the full log. and thanks also for your help. http://justpaste.it/e7zn

Comment: ok, if your remote name is origin (git remote -v to check) try to pull with `git pull origin develop` and then `git push` again, if this will not help give me the output of next commands `git branch -vv` , `git remote -v`, `git log --graph --decorate --all`(firs 50 lines).

Comment: if the question is resolved, my question is `what was wrong, what helped?`

Comment: the thing is your first post was the right answer. I thought that there was an error,however, the error given in last line is about an un-committed feature which wasnt finished. As I said I was working on develop not the un-committed feature. So, I managed to push my changes without any errors. Well anyway thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

make fetch first then push as this indicats that something changed at the remote